# Electron + Typescript + Webpack: Boilerplate Example

Tags: typescript, webpack, electron, boilerplate

I don't know how to start the question, but the main problem is that I can't make the 3 technologies work together: Electron + Typescript + Webpack

I've encountered few boilerplates, but in them either the whole typescript is built with **tsc** (instead of Webpack), or only render-part is built with Webpack, and the main-process (main.js) part is written in pure js.

So I was wondering if anybody has or knows where to find a boilerplate project to start the new Electron + Typescript + Webpack project?

As far as I understand it should be configured to build separately main-process and render-process parts of the application (probably, their configs might be different).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you fixed on Webpack? If not you might want to try [FuseBox](https://fuse-box.org/). I find it much easier to use than Webpack, I don't know if its more limited, but it was always enough for my needs. They also have an Electron seed on GitHub.

Comment: Do you need a example one which you can then expand? Boiler plates have lot of things setup like testing, jslint and all. I was able to work a simple enough template for you with TS+Webpack+Electron for both main and renderer process and its working great. If that much works for you, I will push it to git and share

Comment: @TarunLalwani, sorry, I thought about the term "boilerplate" as a template here. What you described is exactly what I'm looking for (just a very very simple project which can be used as a start point for development).

So yes, it would be great, if you provide access to your solution.

Comment: @MarkDolbyrev, uploaded it here, https://github.com/tarunlalwani/electron-webpack-typescript-boilerplate. Check it out and let me know if that solves your purpose then I will add few details and post and answer

Comment: @TarunLalwani, checked your project, it's exactly what I was looking for. Please, add your answer to my question.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I have added a sample template/boilerplate on below link

https://github.com/tarunlalwani/electron-webpack-typescript-boilerplate

So the idea is to break the code in 3 folders

```
src
|-- common
|-- main
|-- renderer
```

The code for the main electron process will go into `main` folder and for the UI/renderer will go into the `renderer` folder.

Now you want to use `TypeScript` in both and have 2 webpack config, one for bundling the `main` and one for bundling the `renderer`.

```
const path = require('path');

console.log(__dirname);
let common_config = {
  node: {
    __dirname: true
  },
  mode: process.env.ENV || 'development',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: [
          /node_modules/,
           path.resolve(__dirname, "src/ui")
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [ '.tsx', '.ts', '.js' ]
  },
};

module.exports = [
  Object.assign({}, common_config, {
    target: 'electron-main',
    entry: {
      renderrer: './src/main/index.ts',
    },
    output: {
      filename: '[name]-bundle.js',
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/main/dist')
    },
  }),
  Object.assign({}, common_config, {
    target: 'electron-renderer',
    entry: {
      ui: './src/renderer/index.ts',
    },
    output: {
      filename: '[name]-bundle.js',
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/renderer/dist')
    },
  })
]
```

Another issue that one faces is that `__dirname` becomes `/` if do nothing about it. So we include below in our webpack config

```
  node: {
    __dirname: true
  },
```

This make sure that a relative path is available. Now we can use `os.cwd()` in dev environment and use `process.resourcePath` in production. See below thread for more details

[How to run and pack external executable using Electron?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49003829/how-to-run-and-pack-external-executable-using-electron#)

The target for both the webpack config needs to be different. So for main we use `electron-main` and for renderer we use `electron-renderer`

The `tsconfig.json` needs to be different for both `main` and `renderer` and should excluded each other. So we use

**renderer/tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2015",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "pretty": true,
        "newLine": "LF",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "strict": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "allowJs": true,
        "jsx": "preserve"
    },
    "exclude": [
      "node_modules",
      "src/main"
    ]
}
```

**main/tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2015",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "pretty": true,
        "newLine": "LF",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "strict": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "allowJs": true,
        "jsx": "preserve"
    },
    "exclude": [
      "node_modules",
      "src/renderer"
    ]
}
```

The final main thing is your `package.json`, which is below

```
{
  "name": "boilerplate",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "src/main/dist/renderrer-bundle.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm-run-all build run-electron",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.js",
    "run-electron": "electron ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "electron": "^1.8.2",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "typescript": "^2.7.2",
    "webpack": "^4.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/electron": "^1.6.10",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.0",
    "@types/node": "^9.4.6",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.2",
    "ts-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "tslint": "^5.9.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.0.9"
  }
}
```

This is should get your started and then you can add things link `tslint`, `jslint` as you go along

Comment: Thanks for the example, very helpful. What is the advantage to keeping two distinct webpack configs and typescript configs for the main electron process and the renderer?

Comment: @BillDeRose, this is because the renderer javascript is running in browser and electron is running in nodejs. They have two different code bundles, that is why two different configs.

Comment: @TarunLalwani Would have been a perfect solution if it had HMR.

Comment: @TarunLalwani Nice solution, is it possible to do something similar using a react-scripts-ts npm where webpack.config.js is not easily accessible without ejecting.

Answer (score 3):

Tarun Lalwani's answer was pretty great, but I wanted to offer a modern alternative to anyone who stumbles across this page.

https://github.com/hellosoftware-io/electron-typescript-react-mui

It uses electron 15, typescript, and webpack 5. It also supports live reloading as requested by netlander.

My strategy was to setup the file structure like this

```
static
src
|-- main
|-- renderer
```

The static folder holds images, main holds electron content, and renderer holds the js (currently built with react).

I'm also using just one tsconfig and two webpack configs to try and simply things a bit.

I hope this helps anyone who stumbles across this post :)

Answer (score 0):

Been looking for similar here for React & TypeScript but with latest Electron `v16` and Devtools  integration. Using this boilerplate tool for now, specially for Hot Reloading assets and modules (HMR). Not a fan of LESS stylesheet, would prefer SASS which can be easily changed via provided webpack configs.

https://github.com/codesbiome/electron-react-webpack-typescript-2021

(Seems like they even updated it recently with more changes to use a custom Window Titlebar and File menu etc)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30794435)