# How to run and pack external executable using Electron?

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-builder, electron-packager

For example, I have a compiled binary `cudaDeviceQuery` which returns a list of devices as JSON. Here's a piece of code:

```
export default function cudaDeviceQuery(): Promise<CollectorResponse> {
  const throwError = () => {
    throw new Error("Unfortunately your platform isn't yet unsupported");
  };

  const file = __DARWIN__
    ? path.join(__dirname, 'darwin', 'cudaDeviceQuery')
    : __WIN32__
      ? path.join(__dirname, 'win', 'cudaDeviceQuery.exe')
      : throwError();

  const descriptor = spawn(file);

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let outerData = '';
    descriptor.stdout.on('data', data => {
      outerData += data;
    });

    descriptor.on('close', () => {
      try {
        resolve(JSON.parse(outerData));
      } catch (e) {
        reject(e);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

But when I use this function from renderer process `__dirname` is `/`, so I get `spawn /darwin/cudaDeviceQuery ENOENT` error. What's proper way to spawn it in dev envivroment and pack it in production?

A webpack config:

`webpack.config.base.js`:

```
/**
 * Base webpack config used across other specific configs
 */
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const getReplacements = require('./app/app-info').getReplacements;
const { dependencies: externals } = require('./app/renderer/package.json');

module.exports = {
  module: {
    noParse: [path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/ws')],
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
          },
          {
            loader: 'ts-loader',
          },
        ],
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },

  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'app', 'renderer'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
  },
  // https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.ts', '.tsx', 'json'],
    modules: [path.join(__dirname, 'app', 'renderer'), 'node_modules'],
  },
  plugins: [new webpack.DefinePlugin(getReplacements())],

  externals: [...Object.keys(externals || {}), 'ws'],
};
```

`webpack.config.development.js`:

```
/**
 * Build config for development process that uses Hot-Module-Replacement
 * https://webpack.github.io/docs/hot-module-replacement-with-webpack.html
 */

const webpack = require('webpack');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const baseConfig = require('./webpack.config.base');
const getReplacements = require('./app/app-info').getReplacements;

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

module.exports = merge(baseConfig, {
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',

  entry: [
    'react-hot-loader/patch',
    `webpack-hot-middleware/client?path=http://localhost:${port}/__webpack_hmr&reload=true`,
    './app/renderer/index',
  ],

  output: {
    publicPath: `http://localhost:${port}/dist/`,
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      // Css, SCSS, woff loaders are here
    ],
  },

  plugins: [
    // https://webpack.github.io/docs/hot-module-replacement-with-webpack.html
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),

    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      debug: true,
    }),
  ],

  // https://github.com/chentsulin/webpack-target-electron-renderer#how-this-module-works
  target: 'electron-renderer',
});
```

`webpack.config.electron.js`:

```
/**
 * Build config for electron 'Main Process' file
 */

const webpack = require('webpack');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const baseConfig = require('./webpack.config.base');
const getReplacements = require('./app/app-info').getReplacements;

module.exports = merge(baseConfig, {
  devtool: 'source-map',

  entry: ['./app/main/index.ts'],

  // 'main.js' in root
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: './app/main/main.js',
  },

  plugins: [
    // Add source map support for stack traces in node
    // https://github.com/evanw/node-source-map-support
    // new webpack.BannerPlugin(
    //   'require("source-map-support").install();',
    //   { raw: true, entryOnly: false }
    // ),
  ],

  /**
   * Set target to Electron specific node.js env.
   * https://github.com/chentsulin/webpack-target-electron-renderer#how-this-module-works
   */
  target: 'electron-main',

  /**
   * Disables webpack processing of __dirname and __filename.
   * If you run the bundle in node.js it falls back to these values of node.js.
   * https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2010
   */
  node: {
    __dirname: false,
    __filename: false
  },
});
```

As you see, I'm using dev server for hot module replacement, so maybe that is reason of this... I have `server.js` which create server with scripts and then I use it from main process. Here's `server.js`:

```
/**
 * Setup and run the development server for Hot-Module-Replacement
 * https://webpack.github.io/docs/hot-module-replacement-with-webpack.html
 */
const argv = require('minimist')(process.argv.slice(2));
const { spawn } = require('child_process');

async function createMiddleware(port, configPath) {
  const express = require('express');
  const webpack = require('webpack');
  const webpackDevMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware');
  const webpackHotMiddleware = require('webpack-hot-middleware');

  const config = require(configPath);

  const app = express();
  const compiler = webpack(config);
  const PORT = process.env.PORT || port;

  const wdm = webpackDevMiddleware(compiler, {
    publicPath: config.output.publicPath,
    stats: {
      colors: true,
    },
  });

  app.use(wdm);

  app.use(webpackHotMiddleware(compiler));

  const server = app.listen(PORT, serverError => {
    if (serverError) {
      return console.error(serverError);
    }

    console.log(`Listening at http://localhost:${PORT}`);
  });

  process.on('SIGTERM', () => {
    console.log('Stopping dev server');
    wdm.close();
    server.close(() => {
      process.exit(0);
    });
  });
}

createMiddleware(3000, './webpack.config.development'); // A main renderer process
createMiddleware(3010, './webpack.config.server'); // A backend for communicating between renderer and remote server

if (argv['start-hot']) {
  spawn('npm', ['run', 'start-hot'], {
    shell: true,
    env: process.env,
    stdio: 'inherit',
  })
    .on('close', code => process.exit(code))
    .on('error', spawnError => console.error(spawnError));
}
```

Another words, I need to call `cudaDeviceQuery` library from electron renderer process. I'm using a `electron-builder` but it doesn't matter, I can switch to another builder.

Comment: Please add your webpack config to the question

Comment: @TarunLalwani ok, added

Comment: There are two ways. You can use `process.cwd()` or `process.resourcePath`, instead of being dependent on `__dirname`. In development you can use `__dirname: true` to get full path when `__dirname` is called. But for production you need to use one of the two approaches

Comment: Unfortunately, I get `Not allowed to load local resource: file://app/renderer/app.html` error if I set `__dirname` in `webpack.config.electron.js` to true. `process.cwd()` helped! But I'm not sure it good thing for production (in case app called not from their directory). I found out one more way: `__dirname` works in main process perfectly, so I can get full path to file through ipc. Can you submit your answer, then I will accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two things. If you set `__dirname: true` in your web app config you will get the `relative` path of the file from your context directory

If you set `__dirname: false` then `__dirname` will have the full path.

**Development Mode**

You have two options

1. Set `__dirname: true` and concatenate it with `os.cwd()`
2. Set `__dirname: false` and use `__dirname` directly

**Production Mode**

1. Set `__dirname: true` and use `os.cwd()`.
2. Set `__dirname: true` and use `process.resourcePath`

I will prefer 2 as the preferred approach in production

Answer (score 1):

Add this in `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "electron .", "install": "electron-rebuild",
    "package-osx": "electron-packager . Node-RED --platform=darwin --arch=x64 --   out=build --overwrite",
    "package-mac": "electron-packager . --overwrite --platform=darwin --arch=x64 --prune=true --out=release-builds",
    "package-win": "electron-packager . electron-serialport --overwrite --asar=true --platform=win32 --arch=x64 --prune=true --out=release-builds --version-string.CompanyName=CE --version-string.FileDescription=CE --version-string.ProductName=\"CryptoApp\"",
    "package-linux": "electron-packager . electron-serialport --overwrite --asar=true --platform=linux --arch=x64 --prune=true --out=release-builds"
},

"dependencies": {
    "electron-packager": "^12.1.0",
    "electron-prebuilt": "^1.4.13",
}
```

In case of not working for windows use the following:

```
"package-win": "electron-packager . electron-serialport --overwrite --asar=true --platform=win32 --arch=ia32 --prune=true --out=release-builds --version-string.CompanyName=CE --version-string.FileDescription=CE --version-string.ProductName=\"CryptoApp\"",
```

Thanks...