# How to embed a script in electron binary?

Tags: electron

I'm doing long-running computations in an electron app. I'm "forking" the node process using [child_process.fork](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options) to execute a script in a separate process not to block the renderer process.

The app is working fine provided that the script I'm launching with *child_process.fork* is in the directory I'm launching it from. What I'd like to do instead is to ship the script inside the binary (I'm using [electron-builder](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder) to build one).

I've found out that the builder packs everything (including the script I'm interested in) into an `.asar` archive - can it be accessed by the binary at runtime?

[child_process.spawn](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) and using a language other than JS is an option too, but the problem persists - I don't know how to embed the script into the binary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem thanks to [this response from another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49049277).

I've added

```
node: {
    __dirname: true,
},
```

to `webpack.config.js` and used `process.resourcesPath` to resolve the file path.

[child_process.fork](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options) can utilize the [asar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/asar) library, if given a script path inside an asar archive. To achieve this I used roughly

```
import path from 'path';
import { fork } from 'child_process';

const scriptPath = path.join(process.resourcesPath!, 'app.asar', fileName);
const args = [];
const process = fork(scriptPath, args);
```

[child.execFile](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execfile_file_args_options_callback) on the other hand can utilize the asar library to spawn a process of the binary contained in an asar archive. Note that it can only resolve the binary, not its parameters, so if you wanted to embed say a Python interpreter and a Python script in your electron app, you should package it in a single binary or extract the script to the file system and execute using the embedded Python binary or load its content to a variable and execute directly using `python -c "print(44)"` with your script content as a `-c` argument parameter.